# How to move files via batch file but if file already exist move elsewhere?

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy, xcopy

I am trying to move files to a particular folder
(*destination folder*), but I do not want to overwrite any
files. Instead, if the file already exist in that particular
folder (*destination folder*), then move that file in another
folder (*overflow folder*), but keep folder structure.

I tried with `xcopy` and `robocopy`, but It appears that it
can't be done like that.

This is the script I use to move files but not overwrite.

```
robocopy "C:\DummySourcePath\" "C:\DummyDestantionPath\" /E /XC /XN /XO
```

Comment: Why the Powershell tag when your question says batch file?

Answer (score 1):

Now it looks like your goal is to take a folder or directory and take all contents from this folder (including from sub-directory's) and copy it to one main folder. Any duplicate files you want rather to be sent to an overflow rather then to be overwritten.

If you don't want to overwright any files, an overflow folder will work. However what if there are two duplicate files trying to be dumped into the overflow directory? To get around this, we can simply name **{File}** to **{File}(1)**, **{File}(2)**, exc. This part of the script was taken from [michael_heath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9012170/michael-heath) on the post - [batch script to copy files listed in a txt document and keep duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304646/batch-script-to-copy-files-listed-in-a-txt-document-and-keep-duplicates/52305040#52305040).

Essentially we are using an `FOR /R` statement along with an `IF` statement to check if the *target* directory contains the file or not. If it does, the `ELSE` will move it to overflow with further anti-overwright protections.

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem | Configure directories
set "source=C:\Source-Directory"
set "target=C:\Target-Directory"
set "overflow=Overflow-Directory"

rem | Scan target directory for a duplicate file name.
rem | If a duplicate was found, run a function to copy it to a overflow directory.
rem | If it already exists in the overflow directory rename it to {Name}(1), {Name}(2), exc.
rem | The overflow {Name}(1) protection was originally scripted by: michael_heath
FOR /R "%source%" %%i in (*.*) do (
If not exist "%target%\%%~nxi" (copy "%%i" "%target%") ELSE (call :index "%%~i" "%overflow%\%%~nxi" "1"))

rem | Run finished code here or end script with "goto :eof"
goto :eof

:index  source, overflow, count
setlocal
set /a "cnt=%~3"

if exist "%overflow%\%~n2(%cnt%)%~x2" (
    call :index "%~1" "%~2" "%cnt%+1"
) else copy "%~1" "%overflow%\%~n2(%cnt%)%~x2"
```

Comment: That is great and thanks to michael_heath aswell, however one issue I see is that it does not keep the folder structure, rather dumps all into the same main folder, instead of being moved/copied to its same subfolders.

Comment: @RoneJohnson That's what threw me off. Why would you need an overflow folder if you're just coping A folder. So you're wanting to check if the main directory already exists in the destination? Then either copy over or send to overflow (Overflow also maintaining file structure)?

Comment: the files are timestamp sensitive, so I cant overwrite them. The files in the source are the Originals, the files I am moving to the destination are the originals aswell so new orginals get their slot in the orginal folders, and duplicate or edited version go to overflow. I would liek to keep folder structure intact only to the last folder node/name. i.e. C:\house\folderwewanttokeep\files.mp4 to G:\storage\folderwewanttokeep\files.mp4 where the folder "folderwewanttokeep" is the only part of the folder path we want to keep. so we can move "folderwewanttokeep\files.mp4" to wherever we decide

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "source=%cd%\source"
set "target=%cd%\target"
set "overflow=%cd%\overflow"

for /r "%source%" %%A in (*.*) do call :copyfile "%%~A" "move" "report"

2>nul rd "%source%"
exit /b

:copyfile  source [, operation [, report]]
setlocal
set "curpath=%~1"
set "operation=%~2"
set "report=%~3"

if defined report echo "%curpath%"

call set "destpath=%%curpath:%source%=%target%%%"
if exist "%destpath%" call set "destpath=%%curpath:%source%=%overflow%%%"

if exist "%destpath%" (
    if defined report echo     exist in "%destpath%"
    exit /b 1
)

if "%operation%" == "copy" (
    if defined report echo     copy to "%destpath%"
    echo f|>nul xcopy "%curpath%" "%destpath%"
) else (
    for %%A in ("%destpath%") do (
        if not exist "%%~dpA" md "%%~dpA" || (
            if defined report echo     md failed with "%%~dpA"
            exit /b 1
        )
    )

    if defined report (
        echo     move to "%destpath%"
        move "%curpath%" "%destpath%"
    ) else >nul move "%curpath%" "%destpath%"

    for %%A in ("%curpath%") do 2>nul rd "%%~dpA"
)
exit /b 0
```

`move` on same partition is a move in the
master file table only.
`move` to different partition is an actual
`copy` and `delete` on successful `copy`.
`copy` always does `copy`.

I implemented both operations and can be set by the
2nd optional argument to the called label of `:copyfile`
by passing `"move"` or `"copy"`.
`"move"` is default if argument is not `"copy"`.

The 3rd optional argument to the label `:copyfile`
is to output a progress report.
This argument if defined, will `echo` information
(*like paths etc.*) about the operation.

The 1st argument to the label `:copyfile` is the
path to the file to be copied or moved.

The `for /r` loop recurses the `source` directory and
calls `:copyfile` with the path of each file found.
`:copyfile` will set `curpath` to the `source` file and
will set `destpath` to the path to `target`, which is
the `source` path substituted with `target` path.
If `destpath` exist, then `destpath` is set to the path
to `overflow`, which is the `source` path substituted
with `overflow` path. If still `destpath` exist, then
the label is exited.

The `move` operation uses `rd` to remove empty folders
from `source`.

The `copy` operation uses `xcopy` as it makes the
destination folder structure so that `md` is not used.
The `echo f` piped to `xcopy` is to answer the *"file
or folder?"* prompt.

At end of script, the `source` folder will be removed
if empty.

Set the `source`, `target` and `overflow` variables
at the top of the script to the actual paths.

View `set /?` about variable substitution used in
the script. It is used to replace the source
directory path with the another directory path,
to create the destination path.

Comment: Thanks seems to do the trick, I appericate the entire write out of explanation cause at first glace I was lil overwhelmed, but as i read it and took it line by line it all made sense.